# Taking out absolute value on the solution to integral equation

Tags: integration, absolute-value

I have this equation:$$y=2+\int_2^x (t-ty(t))dt$$

After solving it I got the answer $-\ln|1-y|=\frac {x^2} 2-2$ although the book has the same answer without the absolute value in the logarithm, why is this possible?

E:

**Attempt:**

$$y=2+\int_2^x (t-ty(t))dt \implies \frac {dy}{dx}=x-xy(x)=x(1-y(x))$$

$$\frac {dy}{1-y}=xdx \implies -ln|1-y|=\frac {x^2}2+c$$

Comment: I'm interested to know how you found $\int(t-y(t))dt$

Comment: Take the derivative with respect to x and you get $dy/dx=x-xy$, separate and integrate.

Comment: Was $2+\int (t-ty(t))dt$ the original question at the beginning? I'm just a bit unclear about $\int ty(t)dt$ Presumably, you have to integrate by parts for this one but we only know y is a function of t.

Comment: I edited my post showing my work, does that make it any clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rationale for determining the unique solution is embedded in the general solution

$$-\log |1-y|=\frac12(x^2-4)\tag 1$$

Note that to arrive at $(1)$, we already imposed the condition $y(2)=2$.  Therefore, we are seeking solutions for which $y$ actually attains the value of $y=2>1$.

To resolve this further, let's solve $(1)$ for $y(x)$, disregarding the requisite condition.  We find that

$$y(x)=
\begin{cases}
1+e^{-(x^2-4)/2},&y>1 \tag 2\\\\
1-e^{-(x^2-4)/2},&y<1 
\end{cases}$$

is multi-valued.  Upon inspection, we see that for $x=2$, only the first equation of $(2)$ satisfies either the condition $y(2)=2$ or the initial integral equation.  That is, by assumption, the second solution must have values less than $1$ and can therefore, never attain the value $2$.

Therefore, the unique solution to the integral equation is

$$y(x)=1+e^{-(x^2-4)/2}$$

for which $y>1$.

Finally, we can write the equivalent solution as

$$-\log(y-1)=\frac12x^2-2$$

without need for the absolute value sign.